What are some applications of homotopy in topology other than constructing fundamental group (and higher homotopy groups)??
In pretty much all books I've seen, homotopy is introduced for the pure purposes of defining the fundamental group. But, what are some other of  uses of homotopy?
One that I found is that it can be used to characterize path connectedness; Two functions from a given topological space to the space with only a point (and of course, obvious topology) is homotopic, iff all functions between these two spaces are homotopic relative to the empty set.
Furthermore, we can check if a space has holes (in a very geometric sense) by checking if a map of circle into a space is homotopic to a constant function relative to a single point on the circle.
I am also aware of the application in complex analysis where the complex line integral between two points can be shown to have the same value on paths upto homotopy.

What do you mean by "purely topological uses"? The notion of homotopy is the foundational notion for homotopy theory, which is a subfield of algebraic topology and therefore of topology. Every problem that can be solved using homotopy theory is solved on the back of the notion of homotopy, in one way or another. Pick up a textbook on basic algebraic topology (e.g. Hatcher's) and start browsing, and you should have no difficulty finding plenty of results.

From a quick skimming, I only see discussions pretaining to fundamental group and the higher homotopy groups in hatcher. It's not a book which focuses on applications of homotopy I think... @BenSteffan

The whole book is about homotopy theory. Even homology and cohomology, while at first glance not defined through homotopy, are homotopy invariant notions, and this is exploited everywhere. The focus is not on applications of homotopy theory outside of algebraic topology itself, but there's still plenty of material for you: See section 2.B for instance, or read through the exercises for section 3.2, 3.3, or 4.9, or...

Chapter 3. is on cohomology...? @BenSteffan

As by the second sentence of my last comment... But you may also read section 4.3 to convince yourself that cohomology is really just homotopy in disguise.

By the way, for line integrals (and higher-dimensional versions thereof), the right equivalence relation on paths is homology, rather than homotopy. Green's Theorem (Stokes's Theorem in higher dimensions) will tell you this.

A possible duplicate with some weĺl received answers.

Algebraic topology helps predict and control turbulence by analyzing the topological features of fluid flow. This is important for understanding weather patterns, optimizing fluid mixing and designing efficient airplane wings. So does homotpoy theory.

The entire field of algebraic topology / homotopy theory is arguably a very long extended answer to this question, so there are books and books worth of things to say about it.
Here is just one example: on a topological space $X$ we can define vector bundles over $X$, which intuitively speaking are "continuous families $x \mapsto V_x$ of vector spaces parameterized by $X$." A very important class of examples is given by the tangent bundles of smooth manifolds. We might ask: can we classify vector bundles up to isomorphism?
The answer is that under some mild hypotheses on $X$, $n$-dimensional real vector bundles on $X$ are classified by homotopy classes of maps from $X$ into a space called the classifying space $BGL_n(\mathbb{R}) \cong BO(n)$, which can be realized as an infinite-dimensional Grassmannian. When we want to understand this construction for all $n$ at once we are led to a cohomology theory called $K$-theory.
The thing I really want to emphasize about the very striking shape of this answer is that the question does not mention homotopy at all, and yet the answer does; in particular the answer only depends (again, under some mild hypotheses) on the homotopy type of $X$, which is not at all obvious at first glance. This is similar to the case of the classification of covering spaces, which is also a question which does not mention homotopy at all and for which it's very much not obvious that the answer should be homotopy-invariant.
